# drop down menu not aligned

Tags: html, css

**Html**

```css
.mainmenubtn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-child {
  display: none;
  background-color: #16132b;
  min-width: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.dropdown-child a {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Changa';
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 60px;     
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown'>
  <li><a href='#'>More</a></li>
  <div class='dropdown-child'> 
    <a href=''></a>
    <a href=''>Sub Menu 2</a>
    <a href=''>Sub Menu 3</a>
    <a href=''>Sub Menu 4</a>
  </div>
</div>

</ul></div>
```

my issue as you can see in the image [menu not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8q5g.png)

I tried adding display inline or none but it didn't work, I get it as inline displayed,

I want also on hover the color changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.mainmenubtn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-child {
  display: none;
  background-color: #16132b;
  min-width: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.dropdown-child a {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Changa';
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 60px;     
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-child {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-child a:hover {
      padding: 3px;
      height: 60px;
      font-family: 'Changa';
      display: block;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      line-height: 60px;     
    }
```

```html
<div class='dropdown'>
  <li><a href='#'>More</a></li>
  <div class='dropdown-child'> 
    <a href=''></a>
    <a href=''>Sub Menu 2</a>
    <a href=''>Sub Menu 3</a>
    <a href=''>Sub Menu 4</a>
  </div>
</div>

</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an invisible table with border 0 to make it inline...

```css
.mainmenubtn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-child {
  display: none;
  background-color: #16132b;
  min-width: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown-child a {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Changa';
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown'>
  <li><a href='#'>More</a></li>
  <div class='dropdown-child'>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <td>
            <a href=''>Sub Menu 1</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href=''>Sub Menu 2</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href=''>Sub Menu 3</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href=''>Sub Menu 4</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

</ul>
</div>
```

Try it...
**Happy Coding!!!**